# How to Retain Image attachment

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-online, attachments

I am working with ArcGIS 10.3 and ArcGIS Online. I have feature layer with dataset of around 1000 points with attachments.

I called the layer into ArcMap, where I exported the table and cleaned the data in excel. I lost the image attachment when I published the layer back. Further, I tried performing a join on the desktop with the cleaned data so that the other fields would be deleted later online, but I could not published it as a service because the layer source is online.

Does anyone have an Idea how I can clean the data and still have the image attachments maintained?

Comment: The table that you export out does it contain a relationship class to the attachment table?